# Problema al asignar un valor a una propiedad de una clase en Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

Estoy tratando de aprender Typescript. Intento usar un metodo que hace un fetch a una API de prueba, y luego trato de asignar dicho valor a una propiedad, pero no lo puedo lograr.

Este es mi pequeño codigo de hyper novato:

import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

  elem:any

  bringData():any{
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => {
    this.elem = json;
    console.log("promesa ejecutada satisfactoriamente");
  } )

  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.bringData()
   console.log(this.elem);
  }

}
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

El valor esta asignado correctamente una vez resulta la promesa. El problema es que el **console.log** del **ngOnInit** se ejecuta antes de que la promesa se haya resuelto. Añadiendo un return a la función bringData y el then en el OnInit se puede comprobar.

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

  elem:any

  bringData():any{
    return fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
        this.elem = json;
        console.log("promesa ejecutada satisfactoriamente");
      })
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.bringData().then(() => console.log(this.elem));
  }
}
```